# Excel Formula Is unwantedly automatically changing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have created a product referral log and needed to have a system that automatically calculates points for those products once they are closed.

My solution for this was to make a separate sheet which contains the VLOOKUP list of products and corresponding points associated with them. I then place the VLOOKUP formula within an IF statement which determines if the product have been closed and displays the points earned. However, I have run into an issue with my formula:

`=IF([@[CLOSED Y/N]]="y", VLOOKUP([@PRODUCT],'Data Sheet'!A31:B48,2,FALSE`

Every time the formula moves down a row, it changes the ranges on my VLOOKUP list. As an example, with each row the function drops down, the ranges move from `'Data Sheet'!A31:B48’` to `'Data Sheet'!A32:B49` to `'Data Sheet'!A33:B50`.

Eventually, the ranges move outside the range of my list and fails to display the points.

Are there any suggestions for keeping the formula from automatically adjusting the VLOOKUP list? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula should be:

```
=IF([@[CLOSED Y/N]]="y", VLOOKUP([@PRODUCT],'Data Sheet'!$A$31:$B$48,2,FALSE
```

'$' is the 'lock' character for excel (and most similar programs), it stops the program from changing like you described.